# R remove borders of pheatmap

Tags: r, heatmap

I found the [pheatmap (pretty heatmap)](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pheatmap/index.html) package a really nice and easy way to produce heatmaps. In addition to normal `heatmap()` command, it produces a color bar representing which quantity is behind each color, and also does not have unwanted details of `heatmap.2`.

There is a thin border between rows and columns. No problem for low number of rows, but for higher number of rows these borders make the heatmap not so nice. Is there any solution to remove them?

According to the manual, the `border_color=NA` should remove it, however when I create a PDF file from the output, still there exist thin borders between the rows and columns.

Comment: Looking at the manual it appears that you want to set `border_color`: "color of cell borders on heatmap, use `NA` if no border should be drawn."

Comment: I have already done it, but still there is a thin border while I make the output to a PDF file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems borders are a problem of PDF viewer program like Mac Preview and Adobe Reader. They are removed when the heatmap is transformed to an picture format like TIFF or PNG.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; gray border lines in PDF, but not in TIFF or PNG. But I found you can remove the border lines easily in Adobe Illustrator.